# Android:PowerMock work in "test" folder but not work in "androidTest" folder

Tags: powermock

I want to test 2 static methods in Android app. So I use PowerMock for this.

I write 2 tests. One unit test and one instrumented unit test.

My android build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.21"
    androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6"
    androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
}
```

1. Unit test is in folder: **app/src/test/java/com/mycompany/StringUtilTest.java**

Here code:

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(StringUtil.class)
    public class StringUtilTest {

        @Test
        public void isCorrectEmailStub() {
            // mock all the static methods in a class called "StringUtil"
            mockStatic(StringUtil.class);
            String INCORRECT_EMAIL_TO_CHECK = "incorrect_email_some.com";                
   when(StringUtil.isCorrectEmail(INCORRECT_EMAIL_TO_CHECK)).thenReturn(true);
            assertThat(StringUtil.isCorrectEmail(INCORRECT_EMAIL_TO_CHECK), is(true));
        }
    }
```

And it work fine. OK.

2. Instrumented unit test is in folder: **app/src/androidTest/java/com/mycompany/StringUtilInstrumentedTest.java**

Here code:

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StringUtil.class)
public class StringUtilInstrumentedTest {
    private static String TAG;
    private Context context;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        TAG = StringUtilInstrumentedTest.class.getName();
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    }

    @Test
    public void decliningAge() {
        // mock all the static methods in a class called "StringUtil"
        mockStatic(StringUtil.class);
        // use Mockito to set up your expectation
        String expected = "first";
        when(StringUtil.decliningAge(context, 1)).thenReturn(expected);
        assertThat(StringUtil.decliningAge(context, 1), is(expected));
    }
}
```

But when I run this test I get error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest.Reason: com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:284)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest
at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:262)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: PowerMock doesn't work with Android Instrumentation tests. Refer this: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/594